# checking if an input is an integer loop

Tags: loops, if-statement, input, int, stringstream

so I'm trying to make a loop that will only accept integers, it works fine initially, but as soon as something that is not an integer is entered the stringstream it will continuously skip the if statement even if the correct input is used. Am I missing something?

```
# include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
  string str;
  stringstream ss;
  int a;


  for(;;)
    {
      getline(cin, str);
      ss<<str;
      if (ss>> a)
        {
          cout<<"okay";
          break;
        }
      cout<<str<<endl;//debugging (prints the correct input
      str.clear();    //
      ss>>str;        //
      cout<<str<<endl;// doesn't print anything but the endl space
      cout<< "try again";
ss.str("");
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `ss.str("");` inside the `for` loop, so that the `stringstream` will be cleared before you read the next line.

There's also an extra `}` in the code you pasted. Maybe that's related to how that line ended up outside the loop.

Alternatively, you can use:

```
ss.str(str);
```

to fill in the `stringstream` from the input, instead of appending to it with `>>`.

Comment: oops the extra { was from a copy/paste error. I moved ss.str("") inside the for loop but I'm still having the same problem.